# ReactJs Blank page when I click on a link, but after I refresh the page contents show up

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to react and in my app it works fine apart from the fact that when I click on a link in the app to go to another page I get a blank page instead but after I reload/refresh the page contents appear.
I have used CDN files in my react app.
What might be the issue here?

This is how I am loading my urls which look like this

> http://127.0.0.1/my-app/?page=history

and the links look like this

`<a href="?page=home" className="menu-item-active"><i className="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>`

My code for rendering URL's in my index.html file looks like this

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  var page=(urlParams.get('page'));
  if(page=="home")
  {
    ReactDOM.render(<App content={<HomePage/>}/>,document.getElementById('root'));
  }
  else if(page=="history")
  {
    ReactDOM.render(<App content={<HistoryPage/>}/>,document.getElementById('root'));
  }
  else
  {
    ReactDOM.render(<App content={<Login/>}/>,document.getElementById('root'));
  }
```

Comment: Please share your code that you try here.

Comment: @root I have updated my question with the necessary code

Comment: This is an inappropriate way of routing. Please refer React 
 Router for page routing 

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Answer (score 2):

That's not the correct way of routing in react according to the documentation.
A simple solution while using cdn is to include react-router-dom from `https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js`
Then enter the code below as a replacement for what you are currently doing:

```
const { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } = window.ReactRouterDOM;

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={HomePage} exact/>
        <Route path='/history' component={HistoryPage} exact/>
        <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} exact/>
        <Route component={Error404}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can also check out the documentation at [this link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)